# How to execute pip with a windows path

Tags: python, pip

I have both Python 2 and 3.8, when running pip it's version 2. To run pip 3, I tried

```
 "C:\Python\Python38\Scripts\pip3.8.exe" install numpy
```

but it doesn't work

What's the right syntax or alternative ?

Comment: You can try `python -m pip install <package>`, where python is your default interpreter already added in PATH, or actual path like `c:/users/harsh/appdata/local/programs/python/python38/python.exe` This way the installed packages will always be associated with the `python` you used I believe.

Comment: What is the error that command prompt outputs?

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as
`pip3 install numpy`

Just make sure to type `pip3` not `pip`.

Comment: I get "pip3 : The term 'pip3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Comment: Hmm, you can try what @Harsh said, python3 -m pip install <package>